# How do I print out the result in a method?

Tags: java

I need to print out the result of the method power2. How do I put it in the variable long a? There is an error at the part **long a = power2(d,n);**

```
public class homework {
public static void main(String[] args) {
long starttime = System.nanoTime();
long a = power2(d , n);
long t = System.nanoTime() - starttime;
System.out.println("result1():" + a + ": " + t + "ns");
}
public static double power2(double d, long n) {
double r = 1;
while(n != 0) {
    if(n%2 == 1) {
        r*=d;
    }
    n = n >> 1;
    d = d * d;
}
return r;
}



}
```

Comment: `long a = power2(whateverLongParam1YouHaveAvailable, whateverLongPara2mYouHaveAvailable);`?

Comment: what you need exactly ?

Comment: I need to get the value inside power2, like the end result

Comment: What's wrong with `System.out.println`?

Comment: What i need is to put the result of power2 inside long a. Then I can print it out.

Comment: @Zer0 So? get it. Call `poewr2` with the required arguments, right?

Comment: @lealceldeiro Didn't quite understand that.

Answer (score -1):

as easy as this:

```
public class homework {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     long starttime = System.nanoTime();
     long a = power2(TheDoubleVariable, The LongVariable);
     long t = System.nanoTime() - starttime;
     System.out.println("result1():" + a + ": " + t + "ns");
}

public static double power2(double d, long n) {
    double r = 1;
    while(n != 0) {
        if(n%2 == 1) {
            r*=d;
        }
    n = n >> 1;
    d = d * d;
    }
    return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I put it as long a = power2(d , n); ?

Comment: @Zer0 exactly !

Comment: like a red underline

Comment: Did, so what is the problem?

Comment: @Zer0 You need to post the error showing, what is it saying in the console?